# Create scroll markers to show important places in a webpages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create scroll markers to display important places in a web pages.

I don't want to add yellow highlights to the scroll bar but add small bullet icons near the scroll bar depending on the place on the page where the content is located.

On clicking the button the page will automatically move to that section of the page.

Here is a image showing what i want to do.

[image: Image showing the kind of markers i want]

Answer (score 0):

You can add anchors in your website with like:

```
<div id="anchor1" style="position: fixed" onClick="$(this).parent().scrollTop($(this).data('y'));" data-y="500">Marker 1</div>
```

Then you get a fixed positioned element and if you click it, the page will scroll to your wanted y-Coordinate.

Comment: <div id="anchor1" style="position:fixed; top:19.197408716136632; right: 0; z-index=1111" data-y="1135">1</div>  I am using the following code but the div is not showing up on the page. I am using jquery to append this div, it is getting appended to the page but doesn't show up

Comment: you missed a unit after ur top value... like px or %